# kill Winword.exe after the vbscript

Tags: vbscript, process

When i run the below VB script i get the desired output as expected.

But, a new winword.exe process is ran, which i wanted to kill after the script ends.

```
Set Wshshell= CreateObject("Word.Basic")
WshShell.sendkeys"%{prtsc}"
WScript.Sleep 1500
Set wshshell = Nothing

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "mspaint"
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set wshshell = Nothing

Set Wshshell= CreateObject("Word.Basic")
WshShell.AppActivate "Paint"
WScript.Sleep 2000

WshShell.sendkeys"^(v)"
WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.sendkeys"^(s)"
WScript.Sleep 1500

WshShell.sendkeys"c:\testing.jpg"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.sendkeys "{Enter}"

Set wshshell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to close the active process using

```
Wshshell.FileClose
```

or

```
Wshshell.AppClose
```

Comment: While adding the above code it says "Cannot close the window since it is not an active"

Comment: Great "Wshshell.AppClose" helped to kill the created process.
Thanks :)